# Debugging Nested IF Statement for Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, nested

```
=IF(D9 = ”Imperial”,
   IF(D10 = ”Male”, M8, M10),
   IF(D10 = ”Male”, M7, M9)
   )
```

I'm pretty bad at coding but I keep getting a fomrula parse error for this basic nested if statement on google sheets. M8, M10, M7, and M9 are just referencing 6 digit numbers. Not sure why I keep getting formula parse error.

Answer (score 3):

Try it with regular quote characters (ASCII character 034); you had 'smart quote' characters (ASCII character 148) in your example.

```
=IF(D9 = "Imperial",
   IF(D10 = "Male", M8, M10),
   IF(D10 ="Male", M7, M9)
```